# What happens when you set two references to the same object equal to each other?

Tags: java, oop

For example, let's say we have a code snippet as follows:

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle( 5 );
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle( 10 );
Rectangle r3 = r1;

r1.length = 30;
r1 = r2;
r2 = r3;
r1 = r2;
```

What exactly is happening when we set r1 to r2 and r2 to r3? Does everything that happens to r2 then happen to r1, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

At first:

[image]

End: (The `rectangle object` below will be recycled by the GC because there is no reference to it)

[image]

What you did was a reference change, r1, r2 were pointed to different objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle( 5 ); // A
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle( 10 ); // B
Rectangle r3 = r1; // r3 = A

r1.length = 30; // Mutate A
r1 = r2; // r1 = B
r2 = r3; // r2 = A
r1 = r2; // r1 = A
```

Reassigning a variable with will just change the value to which that variable points to.

In the end we can see all 3 variables will point to `A` and `B` reference will be lost.